# Is it possible to double underbrace?

Tags: latex

```latex
\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{=\dfrac{n}{\mu}-\large{1}}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}
```

From the above, I need another underbrace beneath `$${\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}$$`.

This is what I tried:

```latex
$$\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{\underbrace{=\dfrac{n}{\mu}-\large{1}}_{\text{from (2)}}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}$$
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Cross-network duplicate posted: [Is it possible to double `\underbrace`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280651/5764)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a cross-network duplicate has been posted: [Is it possible to double `\underbrace`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/280651/5764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are only missing a brace `}` after `{\text{from (2)}}`. After having added it,

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$$
\ln(L)\approx\ln(L_0) + \underbrace{\frac{\mathrm{d}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu}\bigg|_n}_{\underbrace{=\dfrac{n}{\mu}-\large{1}}_{\text{from (2)}}}(\mu-n) + \frac{\mathrm{d^2}\ln(L)}{\mathrm{d}\mu^2}\bigg|_n\frac{(\mu-n)^2}{2!}
$$

\end{document}
```

produces the following output:

[image: screenshot]

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you very much!